# firebase updating incorrect value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase with ionic.
My issue that my structure isn't recommended by firebase document. 
where table is array and  index is the same for table number.
I know that its not the best practice but dose it can cause incorrect update value, taking in count that array isn't changing by length.
some times the counter isnt sync and wrong.Is it because wrong structure?

```
    // Increment table active rank by 1.
  var fredRankRef = new Firebase('......./events/' + $rootScope.eventId + "/tables/" + item.table + '/active');

  fredRankRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
    if (current_value !== null) {
      if (operator === 'plus') {
        return current_value + 1;
      }
      else {
        return current_value - 1;
      }
    }
    else return 0;

  });
```

Data structure:

```
"tables" : [ null, {
  "active" : 0,
  "table" : 1,
  "total" : 12
}, {
  "active" : 0,
  "table" : 2,
  "total" : 12
}, {
  "active" : 0,
  "table" : 3,
  "total" : 13
}, {
  "active" : 0,
  "table" : 4,
  "total" : 12
}, {
  "active" : 0,
  "table" : 5,
  "total" : 11
}, {
  "active" : 0,
  "table" : 6,
  "total" : 12
}]
```

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem, is is impossible to help. Also: please replace the picture with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: updated me q with code

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any updates?

Comment: Nope. There isn't enough to go on. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin?

Comment: can it be because this is array and more than one endpoint update this array because its a counter?